# Why my code is only returning one output? MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Hi i am trying to get two returns from the following code in MATLAB:

```
function [Xq, SNq] = cuantificacion(x,xmax,xmin,b)
N = input('Introduce un numero de muestras: ');
L = 2^b;
delta = (xmax-xmin)/L;
if(abs(x)<xmax)
    Xq = (fix((abs(x)/delta)) + 1/2)*delta*sign(x);
else
    Xq = ((L-1)/2)*delta*sign(x);
end
p = 0;
q = 0;
for i = 0:N
    p = p+x^2;
q = q + (Xq - x);
end
Px = 1/N*p;
Pq = 1/N*q;
SNq = 10*log(Px/Pq);
end
```

But i only get one return and I don't understand why.

Comment: You are surely calling it as `[return1, return2] = cuantificacion(x,xmax,xmin,b);` and not `return1 = cuantificacion(x,xmax,xmin,b);`, or even `cuantificacion(x,xmax,xmin,b);`, correct? You are taking the return values?

Comment: Oh yeah! Sorry I am just starting to use MATLAB, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ander i was just calling it wrong. I had to call it:

```
[return1, return2] = cuantificacion(x,xmax,xmin,b);
```